# DB2 UNIQUE Constraint that is Case Insensitive

Tags: indexing, db2, constraints

How do I create a unique constraint on a table?
I tried doint this but it chokes on UPPER.

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD UNIQUE(UPPER(MY_COL))
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just _store_ the column as upper/lower case only?  Also, be careful here, because not all cultures do casing conversions the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a function you would need to use the `CREATE INDEX` statement. The keyword "unique" makes it a unique constraint.

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MyUpperIndex ON MY_TABLE(UPPER(MY_COL))`

Comment: Thank you so much Henrik